# Swift 4 Query multiple Core Data entities with the same attribute

Tags: core-data, swift4, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an App which has multiple Core Data entities such as "Run, Walk, Cycle, Elliptical" which all have a consistent attribute called "duration".

I am fine with fetching results from each of these entities within a date range etc, but what I am trying to do is have one query which checks all of these entities at the same time & produce an array of all durations from today.

I realise I can do this with separate queries for each entity but I am positive there must be a way of doing this within one call? That way seems really labour intensive & probably memory hungry?

I have tried a fair few suggestions & am not getting anywhere near the result I am after!

Essentially in basic terms I need something like:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let dateFrom = NSDate()
    let dateTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: dateFrom as Date)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<Run,Cycle,Walk,Elliptical>(entityName: "Run,Cycle,Walk,Elliptical")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"%@ >= timestamp AND %@ <= timestamp", dateFrom, dateTo! as NSDate)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(request) 
        let durationTodayArray = result.map{$0.duration}

        print("Today's Durations: \(durationTodayArray)")
```

Where 'durationTodayArray' would be an array of any times logged today.

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere - I have looked & can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the section on Entity Inheritance in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1).

Comment: The reference by @pbasdf is correct.  Make your four entities inherit from a common parent entity which has the `.duration` attribute.  It is analagous to class inheritance in Objective-C, C++, etc.  There is nothing new under the sun :)